# multiple iterators for map() function in python?

Tags: python, iterator

I know there's a way to have the python map function execute for multiple iterators in one command, but I keep getting syntax or valueErrors, or if it does compile it just overwrites previous iterations or gives the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

```
num = ["1","2","3"]
num2 =["4","5","6"]
num3 = ["7","8","9"]

j = list(map(lambda x, y, z: int(x) and int(y) and int(z), num, num2, num3))
print(j)   #[7, 8, 9]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, j))   #24
```

The goal is to have all numbers across multiple lists mapped from string to integer into one big list, then summed using reduce()

**j should come out to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] all ints**

**the reduce should sum it to 45**

update: this way doesnt work either

```
num = ["1","2","3"]
num2 =["4","5","6"]
num3 = ["7","8","9"]

j = list(map(lambda x, y, z: int(x+y+z), num, num2, num3))
print(j)  #[147, 258, 369]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, j)) #774
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Map with multiple iterators:

Given your desired intermediate output I'd say that `map` isn't the right tool to get a `j` containing the integers 1-9.

That's because `map` with multiple iterators goes through the iterators simultaneously:

[image]

It doesn't repeat, that's just because it's a gif file.

### The problem(s) in your approaches:

In the first iteration it will return `"1", "4", "7"` (the first elements of each iterable) the next iteration will return `"2", "5", "8"` and the last iteration `"3", "6", "9"`.

On each of these returns it will apply the function, in your first example in the first iteration that's

```
int("1") and int("4") and int("7")
```

which evaluates to `7` because that's the last truthy value of the chained `and`s:

```
>>> int("1") and int("4") and int("7")
7
```

That also explains why the result is `24` because the results of the other iterations are `8` and `9`:

```
>>> int("2") and int("5") and int("8")
8
>>> int("3") and int("6") and int("9")
9

>>> 7 + 8 + 9
24
```

In your second example you added the strings (which concatenates the strings) and then converted it to an integer:

```
>>> "1" + "4" + "7"
"147"
>>> int("147")
147
```

### The solution:

So, you need the addition from your second approach but apply the `int` to each variable like you did in the first example:

```
j = list(map(lambda x, y, z: int(x)+int(y)+int(z), num, num2, num3))
```

### A better solution:

But for that problem I would probably use a different approach, especially if you want the "desired" `j`.

To get that you need to [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the iterables:

```
import itertools
chained = itertools.chain(num, num2, num3)
```

Then convert all of them to integers:

```
chained_integers = map(int, chained)
```

This `chained_integers` is the iterator-equivalent to the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` list you wanted as `j`. You could also use `chained_integers = list(map(int, chained))` and print the `chained_integers` before proceeding if you want to double-check that.

And finally to `reduce` it I would actually use the built-in `sum` function:

```
reduced = sum(chained_integers)  # or "reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, chained_integers)"
```

Or the one-line-version:

```
sum(map(int, itertools.chain(num, num2, num3)))
```

### An alternative solution using a comprehension instead of `map`:

Even simpler would be a comprehension (in this case I used a generator expression) instead of the `map`:

```
reduced = sum(int(v) for v in itertools.chain(num, num2, num3))
```

### An alternative solution using a generator function:

That's pretty short and easy to understand but I would like to present another example of how to do it using your own generator function:

```
def chain_as_ints(*iterables):
    for iterable in iterables:
        for item in iterable:
            yield int(item)
```

And you could use it like this:

```
sum(chain_as_ints(num, num2, num3))
```

In this case a generator function is not really necessary (and probably not advisable given the alternatives) I just wanted to mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate over the elements of each list as one long list, it is easiest to just concatenate them:

```
nums = map(int, num + num2 + num3)
```